# GitHub api HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, github-api

I am trying to scrap the data from GitHub Api and getting this error

```
HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

I dont want to use any wrapper library and im confused how to used authentication with python code anybody who can direct me to this

here is code that im trying

```
 response = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
raw_json = response.read().decode("utf-8")
data = json.loads(raw_json)
```

Comment: Have you  tried using a header?

Comment: I have no idea how to use them.

Comment: Sorry can u please give proper example doesnt making any sense to me

Comment: Like this:`from urllib.request import urlopen, Request;link = Request("your_link",headers={'User-agent': 'Defined'});response = urlopen(link) ; raw_json = response.read().decode("utf-8") ; data = json.loads(raw_json)`. Break them as a new line from semicolon.

Comment: can you please tell if I need to use personal token how can i use it thanks alot it works btw